# R : plot multiple chronicles separated on 3d plot

Tags: r, plot, 3d

I'm running some simulations and have a distribution p(a1) for every time step.
What i'm looking for is a way to plot the p(a1) distributions (as continuous lines) for every time step.

Basically something like this but without the edges connected :

[image]

3D plotting in R has always thrown me off so if anyone has an idea on how to achieve this, feel free to suggest. You can use the following code to try out stuff.

```
a1 = rep(0, 10)
t = 1:20
pa1 = matrix(ncol=length(a1), nrow = length(t))
for(i in t){pa1[i,]=a1+i}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `rgl` package for that.

In the code below, you create the density for each empirical distribution, obtain its respective x and y coordinates, and add a third dimension, which has to be same value within each distribution, but different across them (sequentially adding 0.1 for example)

If you run the code, you can then move the plot around to obtain the perspective you are interested

```
library(rgl)

# example data 
x <- replicate(5, rnorm(100))
D <- apply(x, 2, density)
coords <- lapply(1:5, function(i) cbind(x = D[[i]]$x,z = rep(i/10, 512),y = 
D[[i]]$y))


plot3d(coords[[1]], ylim = c(0, 0.6), type = "l", col = "blue")
sapply(2:5, function(i) plot3d(coords[[i]],add = TRUE,type = "l", col = 
"blue"))
grid3d(c("x", "y+", "z"))
```

[image]

Comment: Quite exactly what I wanted. Perfect! Thanks a lot.