# Control space between data lines in a 3D plot

Tags: r, rgl, plot3d

I am new on Stack Overflow. I have a 3D plot, like in this topic : [R : plot multiple chronicles separated on 3d plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48412570/r-plot-multiple-chronicles-separated-on-3d-plot?newreg=5905eeed51a74d508e247caab5b2f673)

Here is a reproducible example (edited) :

```
library(rgl)

# example data
Month <- rep(1:12, times = 7)
Year <- rep(1998:2004, each = 12, times = 1)
Sat <- rnorm(84)
df <- data.frame(Month, Year, Sat)
df

rgl::plot3d(df, type = "l", xlim = c(0, 1.5), ylim = c(1998,2004), ylab = "Year", col = "blue")
sapply(2:7, function(i) plot3d(df, add = TRUE,type = "l", col = "blue"))
grid3d(c("x", "y+", "z"))
grid3d(side, at = NULL, col = "gray", lwd = 1, lty = 1, n = 2)
```

[image]

lines are really close to each other.
I would like to enlarge space between data lines. How can I do that?

Thanks for your responses.

Comment: Do you mean the lines of data or the lines of the grid?  If the former, just plot every N-th row of data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear what you intended to show in your plot.  You have `xlim = c(0, 1.5)`, but then plot values from `1:12` which cause the plot to expand.

If you want to restore the roughly equal sized sides of the plot region, you
can call `aspect3d(1,1,1)` at the end, and it will reshape.  Alternatively, specify an `xlim` range that covers the range of the data.

If you want to clip values of x that are outside the range from 0 to 1.5, then
you can call `clipplanes3d(-1, 0, 0, 1.5)`.  However, that doesn't work well with the grids; they probably won't end up in the right place.

Comment: Thank you ! `aspect3d(1,1,1)` worked to increase space between data lines

Answer (score 0):

To change the gridline spacing,  see `?grid3d`  :

```
grid3d(side, at = NULL, col = "gray", lwd = 1, lty = 1, n = 5)
```

where `n` is the number of gridlines.

To change the density of data lines, plot every J-th row

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm not sure to understand what do you mean by "plot every J-th row", since I plot each year with `sapply`.I edited the block code, now it's closer to what I have with my real data

Comment: @Colsourie  either learn how to modify `sapply` or just write a standard `for` loop with a set of indices like   `seq(1,1000, by = 10)`